# Python os.remove on an open file

Tags: python, linux

```
import os

with open("./tmp.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("Hello")
    os.remove("./tmp.txt")
    file.write("Hello")
```

The code above seems to just be a no-op when I run it. The second file.write doesn't fail but nor does it actually create a new file. Where does the second write go? Is this corrupting the disk somehow?